# How do I construct an object of a derived class in a method whose argument is a base class in Java?

Tags: java, inheritance, copy-constructor

I'm working on an assignment for my object oriented programming class. I've already done what the assignment required, so at this point we're dealing with pure curiosity (in case there were any moral dilemmas at play).

I defined a class called Alien and derived from it three types of aliens (call them red, green, and blue for simplicity). I also defined a class called AlienPack, which stores an array of Alien objects that some character is supposed to fight. The idea is that the three derived classes, since they are of type Alien, can be stored in an AlienPack object. This was all required for the assignment.

Consider the following method in AlienPack:

```
/**
 * Adds an Alien to AlienPack at the specified location 
 * @param newAlien An alien to add to the pack. Will be of type Red, Green, or Blue
 * @param index index must be within the bounds of the AlienPack array
 */
public void addAlien(Alien newAlien, int index)
{
    aliens[index] = newAlien;   
}
```

This method is obviously unsafe.

In order to allow the "aliens" array to hold all three types of aliens, the parameter "newAlien" had to be of type Alien. Unfortunately, this means that I can't use a copy constructor to write safe code (as far as I know).

My intention is this: I wish to construct from newAlien an independent copy which has all the same data as newAlien does, but which does not explicitly reference what type of Alien newAlien is. The Alien class and the Red, Green, and Blue derived classes all have copy constructors. I also know, based on experiments, that newAlien is aware of its type (for example, if I call a method like "printType" on newAlien, it will not print "Alien", but instead will print "Blue" or "Green" or "Red").

How can I perform such a general construction? I should mention that I haven't covered polymorphism yet, and so can't use those features of the language.

Comment: What you're talking about in regard to your hypothetical `printType` method *is* polymorphism ;) That being said, look up `instanceof`

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
public Alien clone();
```

to the `Alien` interface and let the implementations worry about this. E.g.

```
public class Red implements Alien {

    @Override
    public Alien clone() {
        Red red = new Red();
        // Copy properties...
        return red; // Or just return new Red(this) with copy c'tor.
    }

}
```

Finally, just do

```
aliens[index] = newAlien.clone();
```

Comment: Thanks. We haven't covered clone() yet, but I'll keep it in mind. It's an interesting concept.

Comment: The method name is free to your choice by the way. You can even name it `copy()` or something. It was just the mose sane choice of method name. It's true that `Object` offers this method as well, but it's wrongly designed from the beginning on in Java. The method should have been in the `Cloneable` interface, not in the `Object` superclass.